# On which chromosomes were the traits studied by Mendel?

Tags: genetics, history

In his experiment with peas, Mendel mainly studied two traits : yellow/green colours and round/wrinkly shapes.  I've heard that the pea genome is very large and its sequencing is a challenge. However, is there any information about the chromosoms involved in the traits on which Mendel worked ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The yellow/green color of seeds is on chromosome 1, but the color for for the pods is on chromosome 5. The smooth/wrinkly seed shape is on chromosome 7; however for the pods a similar contrast is governed by chromosome 4. The pea has 14 chromosomes (diploid).

[image]

What you mentioned however are not all of the pea genes Mendel studies. He actually studied 7 genes (see table above) but only 4 chromosomes host all of the genes he studied. Mendel was lucky that two combinations don't usually show [linkage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_linkage) because of the large distance between them (on the chromosome 1 and 4 respectively). There was one linkage which he should have detected though between plant height and the shape of the pods (both close enough on chromosome 4); apparently Mendel never published anything on that combination though. I don't know whether it was because it befuddled him or he just didn't study it.

Referernce: Blixt, S. [Why didn't Gregor Mendel find linkage?](https://www.nature.com/scitable/content/why-didn-t-gregor-mendel-find-linkage-26801) Nature 256, 206 (1975). doi:doi:10.1038/256206a0